# ACRA vs UncaughtExceptionHandler Which is better?

Tags: android, acra

I was researching for ways users could report crash reports to developer. 
I read that the google developer console provide this facility but is dependent on the user actually reporting the crash.

I have found two ways to report un-caught crashes.

1. https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup ACRA
2. Using the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

I have my own server back end but I want to know which would be better to use? Im really not sure which to pick :s so I would like opinions from people based on experience and such. Thank you!

Comment: Well ACRA uses an UncaughtExceptionHandler so...

Comment: what about crashlytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. UncaughtExceptionHandler - just catches your exceptions locally
2. ACRA - catches and allows to send exceptions data to you using different ways
3. Crashlytics